# How to output user detail after multiple given input?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a task where I have to create a search table which has a first name, second name, address, mobile, email, street, and other fields.

My FIRST TASK is to enter any one field (eg: first name or last name or street) and get all users matching that one query(like street=Martin street then, I should get all customers in Martin-street or vorname=Micheal, then I must get all names starting with Micheal).

My SECOND TASK is: in the same search table I have to enter one query(eg: vorname or mobile) and get the customer information.

This above two tasks must be done in a single table, I have created the front-end as attached down and in the back-end, PHP is in some mistake and I couldn't find a solution even after a week.

HTML CODE:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <br><br>
<br><br>
    <!--Beginn des Anrede-->
<div class="form1"><br><br>
<div class="names">
    <div class="anrede"> 
    <label for="Anrede">Anrede
        <select id="select" name="anrede" >
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="herr">Herr</option>
        <option value="frau">Frau</option>
        <option value="andere">Andere</option>
        </select>
    </label></div>
    <br><br>
  <div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text1">Vorname</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="vorname">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text2">Nachname</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text2" name="text2" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Ihr Nachname">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text3">E-mail-Addresse</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text3" name="text3" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Email">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text4">Telefonnummer</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text4" name="text4" type="number" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Telefonnummer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text5">
      Geburtstag
    </label>
    <div>
      <input id="text5" name="text5" type="date" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3"> 
   </div>
  </div>
 <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text6">
      Plz
    </label>
    <div>
      <input id="text6" name="text6" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Ihre Postleitzahl"> 
   </div><br><br>
   <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text7">
      Ort
    </label>
    <div>
      <input id="text7" name="text7" type="text" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Dein Platz"> 
   </div><br><br>
  </div>

 <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="text8">Stra&szlig;e</label>
    <div>
      <input id="text8" name="text8" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Stra&szlig;e">
    </div>
  </div>

 <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text9">
      Hausnummer
    </label>

      <input id="text9" name="text9" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Ihre Hausnummer">

      <label class="desc" id="title3" for="text9">
      Hausnummerzusatz
    </label>
      <input id="text10" name="text10" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Zus&#228;tzliche Adresse">
      <div><br><br>
      <div class="sub">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suche">
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
      </div>
    <br><br><br></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){
   $keyword=$_POST['text1'];
   $statement= $myconnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM OL_trans  WHERE  vorname =? ");
   $statement->execute([$keyword]); 
   $key = $statement->fetchAll(); 
   foreach($key as $value){ 
       echo '<br/>'.$value['vorname'].
       ' - '.$value['nachname'].
       ' - '.$value['strasse'].
       ' - '.$value['plz'].
       ' - '.$value['ort'].
       ' - '.$value['email'].
       ' - '.$value['telefon'].
       ' - '.$value['mobil'].'<br/><br/>';
       }              
  }
```

Kindly help me in repairing my PHP code and get me done the above two tasks. A big kudos to one who gonna help me here. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: So what does this code output?

Comment: When i enter Firstname(vorname), it output the user info of the entered firstname.

Comment: Ok so thats FIRST TASK Completed right?

Comment: yeah, but when i enter another field (eg:city(ort)), I want it to produce output like all customers in the city.  Now, how could i combine code and produce output for both search's?

Comment: So you test (IF) the input fields and if you have 2 you have to use another query

Comment: now i changed query to : SELECT * FROM OL_trans  WHERE  ort =?  and it produces all users info in city.  Help me how could i query multiple inputs?

Comment: Ok so if you have 2 inputs .... `WHERE ort = ? AND vorname = ?`

Comment: I changed like that and it results " Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens "

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){
               $keyword=$_POST['text7'];
                In PHP, i declared 'text7' whohc is name of ORT(CITY)(in html code), if i add vorname now i do not know how to add another POST name